# Make a TFindDialog and TReplaceDialog Modal?

Tags: delphi, dialog, modal-dialog

I am using some TFindDialog and TReplace Dialogs in my Application.

How can I show the Dialogs Modally, like the Open and Save Dialogs do? I dont want any user to be able to select any controls in the Application when the Find and Replace Dialog is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simple case of a single-window application I might try something like this:

```
procedure TYourForm.FindButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Enabled := False;
  FindDialog.Execute;
end;
...
procedure TYourForm.FindDialogClose(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.Enabled := True;
end;
```

That is, the first method is the click handler of a button. The second one is the `FindDialog.OnClose` event handler.

For a more complex case I would probably have a look at the source code of `TCustomForm.ShowModal`.

Comment: that would work, I can't believe I didnt think of trying this!

Comment: Maybe you should set the mouse cursor to busy for that form too (Self.Cursor := crHourglass)

Comment: Certainly it wouldn't hurt, but that doesn't seem to be normal behaviour for Windows applications. You don't observe that with TOpenDialog, for example.